# How to redirect to a file with a certain user for creating that file

Tags: bash

Various times in my scripts I redirect output from the terminal to a file or something. Sometimes I'll specify a user for a command but that user doesn't work on the other side of the redirect.

```
sudo -i
# We are now the root user.

sudo -u abc echo 'Something...' > a_file.txt
```

Even though the echo is done as user abc the file will be created as root user.

I understand why this is happening, what I was hoping is that someone knows a way to make it work as desired so that the file a_file.txt gets created with the owner being user abc.

Comment: Have a look at `suid bit` on parent dir: `chmod 2777 storefolder`, then crete new file from different user into this dir!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run multiple commands in a sudo shell and then all them are going to run under the same user:

```
sudo -u abc sh -c 'echo sth > a_file.txt'
```

Or you can use tee pipe:

```
sudo -u abc sthRequiringSudo | sudo -u abc tee a_file.txt >/dev/null
```

Or you can pass your commands to a sudo shell standard input:

```
sudo -u abc -s <<< "echo sth >a_file.txt"
```

You can even have the commands in multiple lines being sent to a sudo shell standard input:

```
sudo -u abc -s << EOF
echo sth >a_file.txt
echo sthelse >>a_file.txt
EOF
```

Comment: `sudo echo` is useless,. jiust before `sudo tee`.  `sudo tee file.txt <<<"hello world"` will suffice

Comment: I assumed echo was just an example. It could be another command that actually requires sudo as the question suggests: "Sometimes I'll specify a user for a command". A command can be anything, not necessarily echo.

Comment: Anyway, I dislike this sample... My favorite is near your last purpose, but I will prefer: `sudo -u abc -s /bin/bash  << EOF...`.

Comment: Yeah, the last is also my favorite. I like that example because it is the one that makes more clear what the original issue is.